# How do I change default printer resolution in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I just installed 12.04. I have a Canon MP970, which it recognized. However, all my programs print at 300DPI Draft. I want to change that to 600DPI Draft. I can do it manually but it isn't sticking and I have to do it every time.

I ran system-config-printer and changed the resolution, but it isn't flowing into my programs (gedit, LibreOffice, document viewer, etc.), even though the change does stick.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

1. Launch your web-browser.
2. Type "localhost:631" in the web-browser's address bar and press ENTER key. CUPS page will open. CUPS is the standards-based, open source printing system.
3. In the main menu click on the "Printers" menu.
4. Click on the name of printer you want to modify.
5. Click on "Administration" and choose option "Set default options"
6. Set settings and click on button "Set Default Options"

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! The system asked for my user and password, I typed root for the user and my root password. This is missing step 7.