# Brother PT-P950NW Print Quality

Tags: drivers, printing, display-resolution, brother, cups-lpd

I have developed a piece of software for asset management that prints it's own barcode labels, this software works perfectly on on macOS with CUPS but I want to use an Intel NUC with Ubuntu for production purposes.

The printer I am using is a Brother P-Touch label printer, they all broadly are similar the specific models I am interested in are the PT-P900W (Wi-Fi + USB) and the PT-P950NW (Ethernet, Wi-Fi + USB).

Printing with my software works fine in macOS, it generates the PDF and uses IPP to send it to the macOS CUPS server, and then onward using LPD to the printer. However this same setup on Ubuntu works but the print quality is awful.

I've tried working with Brother and they're not able to resolve it as they say the software should be able to have a print quality setting. I agree with that view point so I did the work to use IPP to get all the printer settings and discover what print features were supported and try changing them, I noticed on macOS the default resolution is 360dpi where as on Ubuntu it was 300dpi, so I tried changing this, but the print comes out the same.

I have read the PPD file and it has a commented out section for resolution, which if uncommented causes the printer to stop working.

```
*%==== Resolution Features =================================
*%OpenUI *Resolution/Resolution: PickOne
*%OrderDependency: 14 AnySetup *Resolution
*%DefaultResolution: Standard
*%Resolution    Standard/360 X 360 dpi (Standard):      "          "
```

It feels likely this is a driver issue but I cannot figure out how to fix the PPD to enable setting the resolution and I am unclear if the PPD is the definition of how to talk to the printer, or just the GUI options as there seems to be no code in there about how to talk to the printer.

Tl;dr:

1. I am printing from Ubuntu/CUPS to a Brother PT-P950NW and having
   issues with poor quality output.
2. I have working and tested software that uses IPP to CUPS to send it a vector PDF file - Quality shouldn't be an issue it works on
   macOS.
3. There is a notable difference in features implemented between the macOS PPD and the Linux PPD, including that the resolution setting
   which is at 300dpi rather than 360dpi for Linux/macOS.

**Can someone help me to fix this printer quality issue?**

Comment: The difference in quality between 300dpi and 360dpi is minor. Suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Me too, but I don't know where else to look.

Comment: How about just setting the default resolution in CUPS: https://askubuntu.com/questions/267847/how-do-i-change-default-printer-resolution-in-ubuntu-12-04 ?

Comment: Yeah tried that, the issue is the drivers Brother wrote are crap.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the DPI from 300 to 600 helped - it's comparable to printing from my MacBook. Using Brother HL-2170W. I need to change my toner...

Ubuntu 20.04 300DPI
[image: Ubuntu 20.04 300DPI]

Ubuntu 20.04 600DPI (default)
[image: Ubuntu 20.04 600DPI (default)]

MacBook - 600DPI (default)
[image: MacBook - 600DPI (default)]

Comment: That is the issue but the settings don't work for the label printer.

Comment: Sorry, a case of me not reading the question fully. I found your question searching for a solution to what I thought was a similar problem.